# Cannot add files to source control in Clearcase Client machine

Tags: clearcase

I have set up one Clearcase server, one Clearcase client, both on Windows XP. And created the following local groups and users.

### Machine A (Clearcase server)

Group: Clearcase Admin - User: ccadmin

Group: Clearcase User - User: ccadmin, ccuser

### Machine B (Clearcase client)

Group: Clearcase Admin - User: ccadmin

Group: Clearcase User - User: ccadmin, ccuser

Then I logon machine B with ccuser, I checked out source code successfully, but when I try to add new files to source control, it prompted the following error:

No permission to perform operation "make branch"
Must be one of: member of element group, element owner, VOB owner, member of Clearcase group

p.s. I check in/out source code with Clearcase plugin in RAD

I added CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP to environment for my account in both machines, but another error shows up

[image]

[image: Error]

Now the group "Clearcase User" is in the VOB list, is the error due to the different hostname?

### New Update

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to describe the vob into which you try to add to source control

```
 cleartool describe -l vob:\YourVob
```

And make sure your CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP refers to one of the groups (primary or secondary) listed by that command for the vob.

Comment: Thanks your help. Another error is met, I have updated in my question

Comment: @ArthasTsang can you add, on the machine B where you have the issue, the value of CLEARCASE_PRIMARY environment variable? Open a DOS windows, go to the root of your snapshot view, and type `set CLEAR` and then `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview`, and add those two outputs to your question, please.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit lost, the command you gave me list out the info of the snapshot view, but doesn't prompt me for any input. And do you mean adding the owner and group value in my machine A (the server machine) as CLEARCASE_PRIMARY in machine B?

Comment: @ArthasTsang: no the command I gave you shouldn't list *all* the views, only list the characteristics of the *current* view (hance the `-cview` part). You don't need to add anything from `A` to `B`, only make sure that the owner of the view on `B` has his `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` set to "`ClearCase user`" and that his/her view is protected with the "`ClearCase user`" group. Can you copy in the comments the command you typed which returned the list of views?

Comment: @ArthasTsang: Ok (even though I would rather have copied the text instead of putting a picture ;) Easier for copy-paste). Following http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21132158, try adding `HOME-XX5KVTJ6BX\ClearCase user` as secondary group on your vob, with the `protectvob` command. You can do that from machine `B`: `cleartool projectvob -add_group "HOME-XX5KVTJ6BX\ClearCase user" \\xxxxpya\VOB\IBR_VOB.vbs`

Comment: I tried to add group in machine B, but it said "Error: cannot change protection from remote machine" I tried to enable the access by "protectvob -rem", but still no luck

Comment: @ArthasTsang: and what if you try to do it from machine `A`?

Comment: it prompted unknow group name

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7691/discussion-between-vonc-and-arthas-tsang)