# ClearCase eclipsed files hoo-ha

Tags: file, clearcase

I'm having a tough time with ClearCase.  I'm working with a dynamic view.

Somehow, I got two files that are eclipsed.  I compared the folder in my version (with the eclipsed files) with every version on my branch and every version on the main branch.  The original files are nowhere to be found.

I searched for the files in Windows Explorer and found them in the lost+found directory (with a 32 character extension).  This directory appears to be invisible because I can't see it in either Windows Explorer or ClearCase.

I opened a DOS window and ran cleartool.  I removed the files (I had fun typing it all, plus the 32 character extension at the DOS prompt).  I could not find a way to delete them from either Clearcase Home Base or ClearCase Explorer.

I thought this would solve my problem, since there are no more files with the same names anywhere on my computer.

I deleted the eclipsed files and created them again in Qt Creator.  But when I opened ClearCase Explorer again, there they were - eclipsed!  I cannot figure out where the evil twins are.  I tried finding the eclipsed files by using cleartool.  Nothing.  I've tried many approaches I've found online - none work.

I tried stopping and starting the view.  I deleted the eclipsed files again, closed Qt Creator and then opened Qt Creator again and recreated them.  I tried many other things suggested - none made any difference.

If I'm eclipsing existing files, where are they?  I'm starting to think that the real evil one here is the parent - ClearCase!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipsed doesn't mean evil twins (the fact that you add multiple times a file does though).

When you add to source control a file, ClearCase will:

- checkout the parent directory
- access the file in order to create a temporary one (called 'afile.mkelem')
- create the file in the ClearCase vob
- check in the parent directory

I usually see *repeated* eclipsed file when ClearCase isn't able to access the content of a file, because another process prevents it.

Try adding those files after closing the Qt editor.

---

The [OP Rob Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2461124/rob-moore) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985005/clearcase-eclipsed-files-hoo-ha/16985341?noredirect=1#comment24976468_16985341) having solved the issue with:

> I changed the view to `main/LATEST`, and the file showed up.
>   I went to the tree view of that file and noticed that I had a branch there with one version.
>   I compared my branch version with the `main/LATEST` and they were the same, so I deleted my branch and put my label on the `main/LATEST` version

So it is possible that, as soon as the element was added, it wasn't properly selected by the config spec (being a new version on a branch which wasn't part of the config spec), and its state reverted to "eclipsed".

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I checked out the parent directory.  I renamed the eclipsed file.  I created a new file, but it is immediately labeled as eclipsed in clearcase explorer.  I still cannot find the original file.

Comment: Oh yeah, I terminated qt creator before I did any of the above.

Comment: @RobMoore then it must be some permission issue. Check your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9276100/6309), also try to execute your dos session with elevated privileges, just to check if that has any bearing.

Comment: I solved the problem, although I don't understand how.  I changed the view to main_LATEST, and the file showed up.  I went to the tree view of that file and noticed that I had a branch there with one version.  I compared my branch version with the main_LATEST and they were the same, so I deleted my branch and put my label on the main_LATEST version.

Comment: @RobMoore Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility (and added a possible explanation).

Comment: @RobMoore makes sense, since the label is now on the right branch.