# Jenkins user permissions for clearcase checkout

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, jenkins-plugins, cleartool

I'm having an issue with checkout `cleartool` element from `jenkins` 
I've been trying to make `cleartool` checkout from `jenkins` and from external batch I'm running but for both I receive this error message:

```
cleartool: Error: No permission to perform operation "checkout". 
cleartool: Error: Must be one of: member of element group, 
                  element owner, VOB owner,     member of ClearCase group
```

Does anyone knows a simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the value of the environment variable `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`, when Jenkins executes the checkout.
It needs to be [set to the main group of the Vob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276100/6309) you are trying to access (`cleartool checkout <path\to\a\view>\aVob\path\to\a\file`).

And you need to make sure Jenkins is launched with a user account, not (especially on Windows) a system account.